Get default instance of random.Random
How can I get the global instance of Python's random.Random class? The one that is used by the global random.choice() functions etc.

Why you want to access said instance?

To use as a default RNG.

Looking at the source code it is available as random._inst. The underscore indicates it's private so use at your own risk, however it does work.
